# Lazarus program won´t start - stuck at debugging

Tags: lazarus

I successfully created a prototype for my RPG game. But I experienced something strange, no errors are showing, everything "works" as it should, but when I try to run the program, nothing opens. It just gets stuck at **debugging**.... I can´t find any help anywhere, even my professors don´t know. Have a look at the screenshot. .. [image: screenshot]

Comment: Is this the first time you have tried to run the app since the project file was created?  If not, what have you changed since the app last successfully started?

Comment: @MartynA No, I have run it several times before(for checking if everything works fine), today I´ve added a few new procedures and variables and this started to occure.

Comment: Then revert your code to what it was yesterday and reinstate today's changes one-by-one until it starts hanging again.  (make sure you reboot your machine first, btw)

Comment: @MartynA thanks for advice, but I see this as the last option of fixing the problem. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Not that I know of, sorry.  Rebooting and them doing a full build of the project is the first thing to do, ime

Comment: Is your game started? I mean is the games process created after the compilation fishes? If the answer is yes then it is possible that your application does not create main window or that its position is set out of your viewing area. The latter most commonly occurs when you switch from multi monitor to single monitor development system. Also have you perhaps set visibility of your main form to false? These are just a few guesses for possible causes that come to my mind.

Comment: By the way you don't get stuck at debugging. You intentionally start your application in debugging mode, so that you can catch possible errors in your application using debugger that is built into your development IDE. This allows you to easily see where in your source code the error has ocured. Finding and fixing errors without running your application in debugging mode is extremely hard.

Comment: PS: Few advice's. Start properly naming your components and variables. While now in the beginning this might seem unnecessary as you can easily remember purpose of these few component variables you have in your program. But once you start working on bigger projects you could easily get lost with a bunch of components that have default generic name. The sooner you acquire good habit of properly naming components variables the better of you will be. Be mindful that it is difficult to unlearn bad habits later on.

Comment: @SilverWarior:  AFAIK, Lazarus does not have its own debugger, it uses the one provided by the OS (Windows or LInux).  And the Lazarus IDE defaults to starting the app under the debugger.  So it is entirely possible for the IDE to be displaying the project status as "Debugging" but without the debugger actually appearing on-screen for whatever reason.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `Application.Initialize` - does it get hit?

Comment: @MartynA That I didn't know of. In that case I would add another step to check to see if perhaps debugger hasn't frozen or more importantly if there might be a debugger proces still running from previous debugging session. And checking AV software to make sure it isn't blocking the debugger might also be a god thing to do.